# Crew member overboard! Interstellar Space Edition

Tags: science-based, space-travel, faster-than-light, interstellar-travel

I am just curious what would happen to those poor souls whom are thrown overboard while the spaceship which is enveloped in a warp bubble, does the bubble acts like a firewall similar to the black hole version that destroy entropy or do these unfortunate cast away simply found themselves drifting somewhere at the current velocity of the spaceship while their blood boils off.

The warp drive aka Alcubierre drive is powered by a highly classified exotic matter field generator which distort the space around the spaceship forming what's look like a bubble, analogous to crumbling a piece of paper into a ball smearing the wet ink all over the paper.

P.S: as usually you all know the drills so don't hesitate to highlight my mistakes just let it rip Yee Haw!

Comment: You might want to split your two questions into two different questions.

Comment: @JoeBloggs: okay I'll post the other question tomorrow then hee hee ;D

Comment: How could we possibly know what happens if somebody is thrown off "in warp"? This is purely opinion-based.

Comment: @NomadMaker The OP actually specifies the Alcubierre drive. The Alcubierre Metric is a well studied metric, up there with Minkowski, Schwarzschild and Kerr. Unfortunately, we have yet to come up with workable theory for generating a real Alcubierre Metric and thus Alcubierre drive, but we have a good idea about the General Relativity of such a space would be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Their body will be converted to a multi light year long skid mark

The poor soul doesnt intersect the warp bubble every molecule at once. It takes time for the body to transition that threshold out of warp, and during that time, the ship moves significant distance.

Two molecules of the body which were adjacent in the warp bubble are now hundreds of km apart as they passed the bubble picoseconds apart.

The body will be distributed as individual molecules scattered over the route of the ship.

A 2m tall human passing headfirst  through the warp bubble at 1cm/second will take 200 seconds to pass through. If the ship is travelling at 72 lightyears per hour the body will be distributed over a 4 ly region.

They've become a giant cosmic skid mark.

Comment: All the more reasons for windshield whipers on space ships. Not only because they are cool.

Comment: @Erik: one of the hypothetical problems with Alcubierre drives is interstellar gas being compressed into an unimaginably energetic bow-wave on the front of the bubble and then releasing a planet-killing burst of radiation when the ship stops. Windscreen wipers may be mandatory.

Comment: The spaceship isn't moving 72 lightyears per hour. It is stationary. The warp bubble is moving at 72 lightyears per hour. That is like saying that falling into the swimming pool of a cruise ship will turn you into an oceanic skid mark.

Comment: @Aron: I think Ash meant to include the wrap bubble as it is created by the spaceship, the wrap bubble distort spacetime so much that spaghettification occurs to anything that come close but to outside observer they see only "skid marks" left in it's wake ;D

Comment: @Aron: "Lieutenant; we need to get back to Earth in under 3 hours or billions of people are going to die, how fast is the ship travelling?" "Captian I dont want to push the engines much further due to the damage; our sensors report were making 70ly/hr. We'll just make it." Passing janitor: "Actually the ship is idle relative to the warp bubble, the warp bubble is moving in space". Everyone on bridge stares in disbelief. Captian: "Take him to the brig!"

Comment: @user6760 Perhaps I wasn't being clear enough. Locally to the hull of the ship, the physics and the spacetime would be flat, or close enough to flat (Minkowski Metric), otherwise it would be rather unconfortable... Assuming that the poor soul was not accelerated suddenly and unsurvivably, out an airlock, one would expect that there is enough Minowski Space Time for a rescue mission to be mounted, before he/she/it interfaces with the Alcubierre Metric.

Comment: Conversely, should they meet the Alcubierre Metric, yes there are extreme tidal forces, however, you must remember that in the Alcubierre Metric, the wake neccessarily has a negative energy density (which is what drives your ship forward). This means that a crewman being dropped off the back would tend to drift back to the center of the warp bubble. Conversely a crewman that is ejected to the front would be sucked into the singluarity soup that pulls the ship forward, they would become one with the exotic matter greek alphabet soup, stuck like a fly on a windscreen.

Answer (score 2):

If I have to draw an analogy with what happens to bodies being thrown off a fast running train, fast running cars/trucks, fast running boats and fast flying airplanes, the impact with some interface in the medium where the thing is travelling won't be pacific (air/ground, air/water, moving air/still air).

It usually involves some tumbling and rolling followed by physical damages and/or dismembering, due the inflexibility of nature in applying conservation of momentum and energy.

I expect something similar also in this case: once the body reaches the interface between the warp bubble and the space it will start bouncing around before it can be left exit the bubble. Though I wonder if it can leave the bubble at all, considering that nobody has ever complained about a warp bubble leaving its ship behind...

In any case, being in the vacuum of space means that we won't be able to ever listen to a first hand report of the experience. The subject will probably die of space exposure before reaching the interface.